# Hard drive doesn't go to sleep when is not in use

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, mac

is there a way to stop the hard drive when its not in use?

Like an energy saver feature?

I have a Mackbook black series.

Thanks in advance.

l.

Answer (score 0):

Some machines do not natively go into hibernation with Ubuntu installed, my Sony Vaio didnt at first but i found this online and then i was able to put my machine into hibernation when i closed the lid the code is : `sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla`

and then paste this code into the file that opens in terminal:

```
[Re-enable Hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

If you go to system settings > brightness and lock > select dim screen to save power

Comment: Thanks DriftessMadd, The thing is not hibernation, is more if I'm doing word-processing with minimalist programs like TextRoom it doesn't require the hard disk to be turned on. It would be easy to have a feature that you can stop the hard disk like 10 minutes or so if he is not being used.

Comment: The hard disk always needs to be on as it is running all of the processes for the operating system and from your text editor, if you look carefully you will notice that after a certain amount of time you text editor will do an auto-save of the document you are working on.  

There are no options in any operating systems to turn off the hard drive you are using.